# How can I find obsolete "noinspection" annotations?

Tags: webstorm

I just went through a project and resolved all code hints WebStorm provided.

For most of these, that meant adding a `noinspection` comment, because either

- WebStorm was unable to understand the code, but the code is legit
- there is a bug in WebStorm

I reported the bugs and am now hoping that they will be fixed in the next version. But now I disabled the inspections and am losing out on a feature.

How can I find `noinspection` comments that actually have no effect and should be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently possible. Please vote for [WEB-16634](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16634) to be notified when it's fixed